# Bug? Java retrieved PrivateKey and signed with wrong SmartCard

Tags: java, security, cryptography, digital-signature

I am trying to sign some data with Java KeyStore, I was able to retrieve the certificate and supposedly grabbed the `PrivateKey` from the keystore, however when I try to sign it, I **purposely put in the wrong card** in the card reader, and it prompt for PIN, I entered the PIN for that wrong card, and it signed it anyway... wtf?

Say I have 2 smart cards, say `MyTestAlias` and `MyWrongCardAlias`, I grab the private key for `MyTestAlias` however I insert the card which has `MyWrongCardAlias`, and the following code "worked" anyway which it shouldn't! This makes no sense.

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
ks.load(null);

Signature rsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
rsa.initSign(ks.getKey("MyTestAlias"));
rsa.update("Hello world".getBytes());

// this prompt for pin of the incorrect card, 
// but if you entered the correct pin for that card, 
// it would still sign it.
byte[] signedData = rsa.sign();
```

Comment: I think it is not a Java problem. It looks like a card driver bug, which should terminate the connection when it is extracted. I have seen it on occasion.

Comment: Any more information on it? Got link on where you saw it? I'd like to compare and see if it is related or to see if i could troubleshoot it.

Comment: I can not give you more information, it was in a project some time ago with a card from a manufacturer that we observed the same behavior. With other cards it did not happen.

Comment: This really looks more of a CMS implementation issue, or an issue in the underlying PKCS#11 library (if any) or indeed a driver / certificate caching implementation. Java doesn't really manage the references to the actual key / certificate and it is extremely unlikely that that would suddenly point to a different certificate / key. So I agree with pedrofb that this is not in Java (or at least it is **very** unlikely).